# Pandas: How can I substract an array from a column repeatedely

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have monthly average temperature data for certain year, lets say 1900, so the dataframe looks like:

```
year | month | temp
-----+-------+-------
1900 |     1 | 18.5
1900 |     2 | 18.8
1900 |     3 | 21.4
...
1900 |    12 | 18.4
```

Then I have monthly average temperatures that goes from 1900 to 2020, and I want to compare them to the 1900 base

I extracted an array of 1900 temperatures:

```
t1900 = df.loc[df.year == 1900]['temp']
```

How can I substract (without using a loop) the monthly temperature of each month in 1900 from the corresponding month in every year?

If I do `df['delta'] = df.temp - t1900` it works for the first year, but for the following ones, it obviously returns `NaN` since the operation is element wise.

The result I want to have something like:

```
year | month | temp  | delta
-----+-------+-------+------
1900 |     1 | 18.5  |  0.0
1900 |     2 | 18.8  |  0.0
1900 |     3 | 21.4  |  0.0
...
1900 |    12 | 18.4  |  0.0
1901 |     1 | 19.0  |  0.5
1901 |     2 | 18.6  | -0.2
1901 |     3 | 22.0  |  0.6
...
2020 |    10 | 24.5  | -0.4
```

Notice that in the last year I may or may not have the whole 12 months because of missing data

I have already solved this with a loop, and `iloc`ing, and its okay, since I'm filtering data and have around 3,000 rows of data, but the whole dataset has much more records and I belive using loops is not pretty optimal

Is there a way to tell Pandas or maybe Numpy that this operation should be done like repeating blocks?

EDIT:
(I hate to show my code when I know is horrible)

This produces the array of deltas, that then are appended to the original dataframe. It works and all, but its an horrid solution

```
j = 0
delta = []
for i in range(0, len(df)):
    d = df.iloc[i]['temp'] - base[j]
    delta.append(d)
    j += 1
    if j > 11:
        j = 0
```

Comment: Why don't you post the code you already have?

Comment: By the way, since it might not be clear that there exists a better solution, and your code already works, you can ask on [codereview.se] instead (remember to read their help center before asking, I'm not very familiar with that site)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First create `Series` by index from months by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html), so possible mapping original months by [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
t1900 = df.loc[df.year == 1900].set_index('month')['temp']

df['delta'] = df.temp - df['month'].map(t1900)
```

Comment: It works beautifully, exactly what I want. But I don't know what the map function does, I'll study that. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Got it! you pass it an "index" (sort to speak) and it'll return the value, in this case the "index" is the month. Nice.